# Inline if statement in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

Is there a way in Grails to do conditionals inline on an HTML attribute, for example:

```
<div class="${if(sec.isLoggedIn()) loggedInClass}">
```

I'm trying to add a class to certain elements if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
<div class="${(sec.isLoggedIn()?loggedInClass:null)}">
```

Or Try this:

```
<div class="${(sec.isLoggedIn()?'loggedInClass':'null')}">
```

Comment: hmm didn't work but what is weird is that when I run it you would expect to see <div class=""> or <div class="loggedInClass"> but what i get is <div class>. So for some reason using the code like that makes the equal sign and quotes not show up. Not sure why that would happen.

Comment: @Trip that means it evaluated to null. try using a string instead of `null`. Try this: `<div class="${(sec.isLoggedIn()?'loggedInClass':'null')}">`

Comment: nvm the previous post it shows as just class in chrome dev tools because class="" just shows up that way. My problem though now i guess is that sec.ifLoggedIn() is returning false.  <div class="${sec.ifLoggedIn() ? 'loggedInClass':'notloggedin'}">test</div> always results in notLoggedIn. And i know i'm logged in because i have a <sec:ifLoggedIn><div class="logout"><g:link controller="logout">Logout</g:link></div></sec:ifLoggedIn>  and that works correctly.

Comment: @Trip aaahhh ddnt realize u were looking in dev tools. yea for some reason the chrome dev tools does that when it sees nothing for an attribute.

Comment: Any ideas why ${sec.ifLoggedIn()} would be false but <sec:ifLoggedIn> would be true?

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
<div class="${sec.loggedIn ? 'loggedInClass' : ''}">
```

Comment: I agree that this is the best solution

Comment: Tim, similiar to JSP's using `<% %>` tags for inline code, can I use `${}` in grails for arbitrary code, not just statements that evaluate to an expression?